# How to auto start application after windows phone 7 boot completes

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I receive notification of system boot on the installed windows phone 7.5 applications?

Comment: Well, you can't. And more importantly - why would you need to?

Comment: @JesperLarsen-Ledet so you're telling me that WhatsApp users must start the program manually at every reboot??? Shame on WP APIs!

Comment: @djecheleon No, the app can still receive push notifications even though it isn't "running". Clicking on the notification will launch the app and to the user it will appear as though the app was running already. But, since there's no support for true background apps on WP (yet) there is really no need to have anything "launch" on boot. It would get deactivated as soon as the user launched a different app.

Comment: "To have a continuously running app" - such as Anti-Virus, Anti-Malware etc... these should be running from boot to shutdown. There are a miriad of reasons for this ... why do people keep asking such silly questions as "Why would you need to?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a point, but due to security this is not possible with windows phone 7

Answer (score 1):

You can't start an application automatically => security
The user should always know when an application is launched.

Comment: The idea that the user should know and MUST know when an app starts are very different. If you check your task manager you will see hundreds of processes running - many of which you did not ask for. 
What about  applications that the user does want run each time but keeps forgetting to put on?